# how to add a vertex in a JGraphX by right click on the mouse

Tags: vertex, jgraphx

I would like to add a vertex in a JGraphX at a position indicated by the user just by right click on the mouse 
How can I possibly achieve that

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You are unlikely to get any answers if you don't show some effort. Do you have any code? SO is to help fixing bugs, not to write all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
graph.getGraphComponent().getGraphControl().addMouseListener(...)
```

And then insert the vertex when the user clicks:

```java
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
         graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
         try {
             // this method is useful if you have a grid, zoom...
             mxPoint mousePos = graph.getGraphComponent().getPointForEvent(e, false);
             graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, "Hello", mousePos.getX(), mousePos.getY(), 80, 30);
         } finally {
             graph.getModel().endUpdate();
         }
    }
}
```

You can then check if cell is not null and is a vertex.